# No FileSystem for scheme: wasb error in Hadoop 2.7

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am trying to establish the connection between hadoop and Azure storage. 
I have added the property in core-site.xml mentioned here: [Link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-azure/index.html), still getting the error

> No FileSystem for scheme: wasb

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the required Java library `hadoop-azure` into your Hadoop lib path. You can download from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure).

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes, I have added hadoop-azure-2.7.0.jar and azure-storage-2.0.0.jar files into my hadoop lib path. Also I have set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable to indicate the path to the jars in my hadoop-env.sh